# Call service on each different thread and wait for all service reponse

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

As I am working on one `Windows service` project, I am finding trouble to integrate below functionality.

1. I need to `call 5 different web services on 5 different thread` in one call (in single method).
2. I must `have to wait for all 5 service's response` and then I have to perform next task.

Question: How would I `wait for all service's response which is called by each different thread?` and then I perform my next task moving further.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am trying to do this by calling delegate method on each different thread (by creating new thread).. by How would I wait for each service response which is called on each different thread? so, short question is... How would I wait for each service response? which all are calling on different thread....

Comment: What if one of the service's throws an exception? Do you need the state of each thread?

Comment: Alex, my each method bound to specific time limit.. e.g. Thread.Join(5000) // milisecond..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using .NET 4.0, you can use the Task Parallel Library.

Start each web service call with a new Task and then call Task.WaitAll passing arraying of tasks created.

```
Task[] taskList = new Task[5];
taskList[0] = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> ServiceCall1());
taskList[1] = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> ServiceCall2());
taskList[2] = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> ServiceCall3());
taskList[3] = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> ServiceCall4());
taskList[4] = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> ServiceCall5());
System.Thread.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(taskList);
```

Comment: Oh, that's simpler than my solution. But can you really make sure you'll get 5 concurrent tasks and not less?

Comment: Not guaranteed to run on 5 separate threads because the TPL (TaskFactory) will execute the Tasks the most "effecient" way possible. Creating new threads is an expensive call and TPL will reuse idle threads. A more performant method would be to use Async calls to web services (As mentioned below in zmbq's answer). Because the threads are idle when waiting for a response from the web service, if the calls were made Async, then the threads can be reused for something else.

Comment: I would go with something like this. Except that `using System.Threading.Tasks;` would help here a lot. And you don't need a lambdas here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Thread.Join()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join.aspx) method in order to wait on a thread.

1. Create a new thread per service call:

   ```
   var service1 = new Thread(() => StartService1());
   var service2 = new Thread(() => StartService2());
   var service3 = new Thread(() => StartService3());
   var service4 = new Thread(() => StartService4());
   var service5 = new Thread(() => StartService5());
   ```
2. Wait for all threads to terminate:

   ```
   if (service1.Join() && service2.Join() && service3.Join() && 
       service4.Join() && service5.Join())
       // Continue...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a couple of things. First option, you can spawn 5 threads from your service, have each thread contact a web-service, and wait for all the threads to finish in your main thread (you can call Thread.Join on all of them - just call Join on the first thread, then on the second etc...), and when they're all done continue your processing.

It's the simplest thing. Although if you care about performance and scale, you might want to use asynchronous communications, and call the 5 services on the main thread and wait for 5 callbacks. I'd worry about that only if performance becomes an issue.

Comment: zmbq, I really don't want to use Join() on each Thread call.. like call 1st thread join, then 2nd thread Join.. I don't want to do like this... Can't we have other idea or other way to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with Joining the 5 threads? 
If you don't want it, you can create an Event for each of the threads, signal it when they're done, and WaitHandle.WaitAll on the 5 events instead of Joining.

In WinAPI you could have WaitForMultipleObjects() on thread handles, but I don't think you can get a WaitHandle from a .NET Thread object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.Invoke`

```
void ServiceN()
{
    /////
}

Parallel.Invoke(Service1, Service2, Service3, Service4, Service5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Fask.Factory Class. This way, you could add various checks or handle exceptions  / timeouts of child-processes.

```
Task parent = new Task(() =>
  {
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var tf = new TaskFactory<Int32>(cts.Token,
                                    TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent,
                                    TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously, TaskScheduler.Default);
    var childTasks = new[] {
        tf.StartNew(() => StartService1()),
        tf.StartNew(() => StartService2()),
        tf.StartNew(() => StartService3()),
        tf.StartNew( () => StartService4()),
        tf.StartNew( () => StartService5())
     };
  });

  parent.ContinueWith(p =>
  {
   //(..do something..)
  }, TaskContinuationOptions.None);
  parent.Start();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the System.Threading.ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads ?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        System.Threading.ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(5 ,5);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(p => { Console.WriteLine(p.ToString()); System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000); }, i);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
```

**For Update :**

And you also could revert it after creating threads like

```
        int a, b;
        ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out a , out b);

        ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(5, 5);

        // your code 

        ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(a, b);
```

Comment: I wouldn't do that. The service may be using the threadpool for other things, and you don't want to mess with the defaults unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: I don't think the question is about limiting execution to 5 threads. And even if it were, modifying global state like doesn't seem like a good idea.